# In some NMEA GPGGA frame, what is the UTC timestamp?

Tags: gps, nmea

In some NMEA GPGGA frame, there is an UTC Timestamp. What timestamp is this? It could be:

- The NMEA frame reception timestamp
- Some satellite transmission timestamp
- The NMEA frame *start of build* timestamp

Does the standard contains information about that?

Answer (score 0):

The UTC Time stamp in the NMEA *GGA* frame refers to the moment when the position contained in the frame was computed. The standard contains full information about that.